# Подключиться через RDP к компьютеру в офисе

Tags: openvpn, rdp

Работодатель прислал конфиг OpenVPN, данные для аутентификации.
OpenVPN установил, конфиг установил, подключился.
Далее работодатель пишет:

> После подключения - будет доступна подсеть 192.168.0.0/24 Заходить по
>   RDP на IP своей машины

IP моей машины в офисе 192.168.0.107
В виндовом RDP прописываю компьютер 192.168.0.107 для подключения:
"Удаленному рабочему столу не удалось подключиться к удаленному компьютеру...".
Все ли я правильно сделал? Зачем он сказал мне про подсеть 192.168.0.0/24?

Comment: Можно проверить, пингуется ли что-нибудь из этой сети и правильно ли настроились маршруты. Не знаю, как в винде, но в Tunnelblick для OS X мне некоторые маршруты пришлось писать в конфиг руками, потому что они не подцепились с сервера.

Comment: Тут до меня дошло, что, возможно, у компа в офисе не разрешен удаленный доступ. Я сам его не включал, включали ли его кто-то до меня - не знаю, но вряд ли.

Comment: В общем, спящий режим отключил, удаленный доступ разрешил. Все равно не работает.

Comment: А что с пингом до сетки?

Comment: Для подключения к RPD через OpenVPN тебе поможет [эта статья](https://blog.vpsville.ru/blog/howto/223.html).